# panda cumulative subtraction

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column in the dataframe called Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight:

```
sample_time Acid Totalizer  Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight hermes_run
0.51    0   3476.2  H11958-5
52.59   0   3437    H11958-5
72.73   0   3336.2  H11958-5
96.14   0   3224.9  H11958-5
120.23  0   3123.4  H11958-5
142.21  0   3039.4  H11958-5
166.12  0   2947    H11958-5
191.3   0   2855.3  H11958-5
216.48  0   2783.9  H11958-5
239.97  0   2734.2  H11958-5
```

when i tried to use the code below, it gave me an error "ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column feed_difference".

When i print "feed_weight", its not in a single column. So instead, it look like this:

```
Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight     0      1      2      3     4     5     6  
hermes_run                                                                 
H11958-5                     39.2  100.8  111.3  101.5  84.0  92.4  91.7
```

How can I get it to read in a single column?

```
feed_weight = RCS_df.groupby('hermes_run').apply(lambda x: x['Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight'].sub(x['Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight'].shift(-1))) # g
#RCS_df['Weight_draw'] = Weight_draw.reset_index(level = 0, drop=True) # kg
feed_difference = feed_weight.shift(1)
feed_difference = feed_difference.fillna(0)
RCS_df['feed_difference'] = feed_difference.reset_index(level = 0, drop=True) # g
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible input

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `RCS_df.head().to_dict(orient='list')`?

Comment: sorry about that. I have included the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is unclear, so based on this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight': [5000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]})
```

You can compute the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['cumsum'] = (-df['Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight'].diff()).fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
   Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight  cumsum
0                         5000     0.0
1                         4000  1000.0
2                         3000  2000.0
3                         2000  3000.0
4                         1000  4000.0
```

Comment: gave the same error. and i edited the input

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
df['feed_difference'] = df['Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight'].iat[0] - df['Adjusted Feed Vessel Weight']
```

Comment: gave the same error. and i edited the input

Comment: I have run your code, and I don't get any `ValueError`. Also, your question has changed considerably (as before you did not mention that the dataframe has to be grouped by `hermes_run`), that the current answers do not make sense anymore. Please provide a minimal reproducible input data and desired output.